# finding roots of an expression y = f(x) for different values of y using scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have the following function.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def func(x):
    theta = np.arccos(1 - 2*x)
    return 2*(theta - np.sin(theta))
```

**Question: I want to find the roots of the expression `y = func(x)` for different values of `y`.** For example if `y =1` I can modify the above function as

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def func(x):
    theta = np.arccos(1 - 2*x)
    return 2*(theta - np.sin(theta)) - 1

initial_guess = 0
sol = optimize.root(func, initial_guess)
```

To obtain the desired root. Let us assume that such roots exist and we know appropriate initial guesses for all the different y values.

**What modifications do I need to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vary the left hand side you could add an extra argument to your `func` and then pass this via the `args` keyword of [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html) (keeping [rths answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45070975/2528453) in mind) :

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def func(x, lhs):
    theta = np.arccos(1 - 2*x)
    return 2*(theta - np.sin(theta)) -  lhs

initial_guess = 0.001
lhs = 1
sol = optimize.root(func, initial_guess, args=(lhs,))
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your initial_guess, which is just the point of the singularity of your function. Therefore if you shift initial_guess a bit you can obtain a nice solution....

```
>>> initial_guess = 0.001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
>>> sol = optimize.root(func, initial_guess)
>>> sol                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    fjac: array([[-1.]])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     fun: array([ -2.22044605e-16])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 message: 'The solution converged.'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    nfev: 11                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
     qtf: array([  2.99071878e-12])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
       r: array([-3.71631332])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  status: 1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 success: True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
       x: array([ 0.46328511])                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
>>>
```

NOTE. Due to problem singularity, you cannot obtain numerical solution if your initial guess is negative or the zero.